# Not able to import cv2 module

Tags: python, flask, pip, pycharm

This is what I'm trying to do:

`import cv2`

I am running this code in *Pycharm* trying to create a **flask server**
it states that `no module named cv2` exists but when I try to install *OpenCV* I get this message:

```
PS C:\Users\sarthak sanwal\ML_Project2_ImageClassification> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\sarthak sanwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.7.0.72)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\users\sarthak sanwal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.20.0)
```

*OpenCV* was working fine on jupyter notebook in the same folder, but the module error only occurs when using Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a module refuses to import but Pip says it's already installed, the problem derives from the fact that pip is installing to a different instance/environment than you are trying to import the module from. There's a couple ways to check this. 'pip list' (run within your commandline/terminal instance) will display all pip'd packages, and you can get a bit crafty with this and run that same command within the actual python environment using the OS module. Open up your python instance, `import os`, and then run `os.system('pip list')`. This will call pip from the instance *you are using!* If opencv is present and still refuses to import, there might be a larger problem.

However, one quick check you can do is to create a new python venv, activate that venv, pip install opencv, and then start python. That way (hypothetically speaking) you can be certain that you are running the same instance that you are installing to.

Here's the documentation on how to set up a venv if that's new territory: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html